# Receive logs from AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

I got severals cloudwatch filter for cloudtrails logs, for example:

```
{ ($.eventName = "ConsoleLogin") && ($.additionalEventData.MFAUsed = "No") }
```

Each filter trigger an alarm and I receive an SNS notification on my mailbox telling me something like `A user has logged in withtout MFA`

But what **I would like to receive is the log line from cloudwatch that triggered this alarm**, so i could know immediately which user is faulty by parsing the log, and trigger a bot that would ask the user to fix this, without having to go to cloudwatch , check manually and contact the user myself.

I could make a program that does this somehow automatically, but I would like to make sure first that there is not a proper AWS way to do it already.

Is there any way to receive automatically the logs in the mail, or by any other automatic means?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using `$.userIdentity`?

`$.userIdentity` got the following attributes:

- `type`
- `principalId`
- `arn`
- `accountId`
- `userName`

With the `arn` of the user you can do nearly everything :-)

Comment: Im sorry, i don't get what you mean ? userIdentity is part of the logs from cloudtrail, but from the mail i receive from SNS, there is no information about userIdentity, so how could i correlate those 2 together (SNS with Cloudtrail logs) can you explain?